# Keep data in grid after clearing context

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have a DataGrid and on SelectionChanged event I'm clearing some entities from the dataContext (RIA ) and then load them again .

The issue is that two columns of the dataGrid are binded through a DataConverter to some of the entities I'm clearing so whenever I do the clearing , the data in the entire gridview for the two columns is becoming null.

The clear->load operation is needed because I'm getting data for another dataform based on the selected item in the datagrid.

Any ideas on how I should accomplish this type of situation, 4 days had passed I couldn't find a solution.

thanks in advance,

Comment: You need to maintain two lists.

Comment: Could you please elaborate - Akansha ?

Comment: Maintain one list which is binded to UI and you can make change to the other list. Because as the list is binded to the UI, any operations(add/delete) will directly reflect on UI. You can also try changing the UpdateSourceTrigger property. Please find the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507883/UpdateSourceTrigger-Property-in-WPF-Binding